# Kendo UI grid custom filter with default functionality outside of the box

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to set up the kendo filter something like filter we have on online sales websites.
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW1ra.png)

In here programs will be associated with Groups and Schools and will have a start and end date. I was setting up the filter using custom code, can we somehow update kendo grid filter menu to get this type of layout for the filtering? 
Here None of the information in filter area is visible in the grid (School, dates and groups).

Thanks in advance

Comment: @sean ch Thanks for the help, I don't want to use the "filterMenuInit" event to show the filter menu, it should be outside the grid to have it more visible to user (UX). Also the fields for filtering will not be visible in grid as columns etc.

Comment: there is no built in way to have murtiple filters what you can do it make a seperate control for checkbox and fire read and refresh on grid accordingly

Comment: fields for filtering will not be visible in grid as columns . For this you can just hide the intended coloumn

Comment: @sean Ch, Extremely sorry, Doing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below proof of concept.

This is just a concept that it is possible to achieve what you doing , there is certainly more research need to be done  and  better way to handle checkboxes checking and unchecking the purpose is to provide a concept on how to achieve it

- You will need to learn more about filtering in case both checkboxes are checked and other possibilities and for sure you can find help on that either in telerik documentation or stackoverflow.

Here is the JSBIN http://jsbin.com/bakediseci/edit?html,js,output

**FOR HIDDEN COLUMN Filter SEE THIS** [FILTER HIDDEN COLUMN](http://jsbin.com/cijexucaci/edit?html,js,output)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<span> Group1 <input type="checkbox" id="group1"/><br/>
<span> Group2 <input type="checkbox" id="group2"/>  

<br/>
<br/>

Date: <input id="date" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="grid"></div>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [
  { name: "Paul", birthDate: new Date("1948/12/08"),Group:"Group1" },
  { name: "Janet", birthDate: new Date("1952/02/19"),Group:"Group1" },
  { name: "Nancy", birthDate: new Date("1963/08/30"),Group:"Group2" },
  { name: "Steven", birthDate: new Date("1937/09/19"),Group:"Group2" }
];

$(document).ready(function() {    
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    columns: [      
      {field: "birthDate", format: "{0:d}" },
      {field:"name"},
      {field:"Group"}
    ]
  }).data("kendoGrid");


  $(document).ready(function() {
    //set initial state.
    $('#group1').val($(this).is(':checked'));
    $('#group2').val($(this).is(':checked'));

    $('#group1').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {          
          $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({field:"Group",operator:"eq",value:"Group1"});        
        }else {
         grid.dataSource.filter({});
        }       

    });

     $('#group2').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {          
          $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({field:"Group",operator:"eq",value:"Group2"});        
        }else {
         grid.dataSource.filter({});
        }       

    });
});

  $("#date").kendoDatePicker({
    change: function() {
       var value = this.value();
       if (value) {
         grid.dataSource.filter({ 
           field: "birthDate", 
           operator: "eq", 
           value: value 
         });
        } else {
         grid.dataSource.filter({});
        }
    }
  });    
});
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: output]

**Research and Helpfull links that you will need down the road**

There was definitely research and source used  you will need to go through
them again to make it solid .

- http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-implement-a-custom-filter#2296030
- http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-filters-to-grid-s-source

  > user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time buddy, This is surely gonna work though I followed some other way to get the desired functionality (Because of dead lines and other stuff I had to get done in app I was working on). At the moment passing the filter criteria as data to the action and filtering records on server side not client side. I will try your method later this weekend too.

Comment: @you are welcome . please keep posted with you outcome . I really liked your UX based idea to through filter out of the grid